# java.util.Properties doesn't work properly when initializing it with another instance of java.util.Properties

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka

This code works:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.{ConsumerConfig, KafkaConsumer}

import java.util.Properties

object KafkaConsumerWithAuth extends App {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "redacted")
    props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.setProperty("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
    props.setProperty("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")
    props.setProperty("sasl.jaas.config", "redacted")
    props.setProperty("ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "")
    props.setProperty("ssl.truststore.location", "redacted.jks")
    props.setProperty("ssl.truststore.password", "redacted")

  lazy val consumer = new KafkaConsumer(props)

  println(consumer.listTopics())
}
```

but this code doesn't:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.{ConsumerConfig, KafkaConsumer}

import java.util.Properties

object KafkaConsumerWithAuth extends App {
    val props = new Properties({
      val props = new Properties()
      props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "redacted")
      props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
      props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
      props.setProperty("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
      props.setProperty("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")
      props.setProperty("sasl.jaas.config", "redacted")
      props.setProperty("ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "")
      props.setProperty("ssl.truststore.location", "redacted")
      props.setProperty("ssl.truststore.password", "redacted")
      props
    })


  lazy val consumer = new KafkaConsumer(props)

  println(consumer.listTopics())
}
```

How come? I wanted to program it this way, because I wanted `props` to also be lazy, `setProperty` triggers execution if you do it like this:

```
lazy val props = new Property()
props.setProperty(..., ...) // this triggers execution, so I can't go with this approach
```

When I run the code that doesn't work, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value null for configuration key.deserializer: must be non-null.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.appendDeserializerToConfig(ConsumerConfig.java:630)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:671)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:652)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:632)
    at main.KafkaConsumerWithAuth$.consumer$lzycompute(KafkaConsumerWithAuth.scala:23)
    at main.KafkaConsumerWithAuth$.consumer(KafkaConsumerWithAuth.scala:23)
    at main.KafkaConsumerWithAuth$.delayedEndpoint$main$KafkaConsumerWithAuth$1(KafkaConsumerWithAuth.scala:25)
    at main.KafkaConsumerWithAuth$delayedInit$body.apply(KafkaConsumerWithAuth.scala:7)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at main.KafkaConsumerWithAuth$.main(KafkaConsumerWithAuth.scala:7)
    at main.KafkaConsumerWithAuth.main(KafkaConsumerWithAuth.scala)
```

So, it looks like the inner `java.util.Properties` object wasn't copied properly.

I tried the same approach with java, when you have 1 `java.util.Properties` instance and you create another one with it, it also doesn't work:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;

import java.util.Properties;

public class KafkaConsumerJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "redacted");
        props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.setProperty("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
        props.setProperty("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN");
        props.setProperty("sasl.jaas.config", "redacted");
        props.setProperty("ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "");
        props.setProperty("ssl.truststore.location", "redacted");
        props.setProperty("ssl.truststore.password", "redacted");
        Properties props2 = new Properties(props);

        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props2);
        System.out.println(consumer.listTopics());
    }
}
```

Comment: Note there's no benefit of having the properties lazy in the code you've shown.

Comment: @GaëlJ I didn't show the whole code, but there is. Imagine you have a test that only calls one method inside your class, and that method doesn't depend on the state of that class, so you don't have to initialize it. The thing is that I don't want the state to be initialized, because its logic is complex, so I just create an object, without initializing the state, because everything is lazy and call the method that I need.

Comment: @GaëlJ I said the logic is complex in the sense that there are external services initialized in there, kafka, pushgateway, (there's also argument parsing etc). And I don't want them to be initialized in my test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `props1.putAll(props2)` if you want to merge the two.

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation, the constructor `Properties(Properties)` is used to set a list of default property values, not to set the property values.

Comment: Could you expand on what are default values and why this doesn't work for OP use case?